# Run Asynchronous tasks in Batch

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am running one stored procedure asynchronously (I need to run the same SP around 150 times) like this:-

```
var queryTask = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
      queryTask.Add(da.ExecuteSPAsync("Async" + i.ToString()));
}
Task.WhenAll(queryTask).Wait();
```

Now, it will create 150 `Tasks` and execute them. Can I split these tasks in batches and run them? Will that decrease the load on SQL server side?

Or shall I consider TPL to run it? Like this:-

```
Parallel.For(0, 150, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 },
              x => da.ExecuteSP("PPWith5Threads" + x.ToString()));
```

Which one is better in terms of performance? This is just an example for demonstation purpose, in actual I am having a collection of *custom type* on which I need to execute some SP.

Comment: if you want to batch up async tasks, you want to implement a semaphore, and each thread should wait on that semaphore. This won't exactly batch, but will prevent all 150 tasks firing off in one go. IMHO better than batching

Comment: @CallumLinington Can't that be achieved simply with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` on the `Parallel.For`? That'll limit the concurrent tasks to 5 in this case.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth you can do, I think you get more flexibility around using semaphores.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth This isn't CPU bound work, so if you do that you're creating tons and tons of threads just to have them all sit there doing nothing.

Comment: @Servy I thought this just schedules 5 tasks at a time?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No, `Parallel.For` is specifically created for CPU bound work and creates new threads in order to do the work in parallel, rather than being designed to work with inherently asynchronous operations that can simply be started and don't need any additional threads to do work.

Comment: @Servy Ah I see, didn't realise it was targeted specifically at that. Being honest, never used it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth You should be able to tell just from the signature of the method that it doesn't accept `Task` returning delegates.

Comment: If you could effectively run 8 things at once, why would you want to batch?  I assume each process you want to run finishes in a different amount of time, running them in batch means that each batch will be only running one process for some amount of time instead of 8.  Why not just figure out how many tasks you can run a once, effectively, and keep running that many until they're all done?

Comment: @Servy Perhaps, but that doesn't imply anything about the internal implementation. Just reading the docs now and it doesn't seem to mention use for only CPU-bound situations.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It absolutely *does* imply a *lot* about the internal implementation.  It means it can only ever accept synchronous operations, not asynchronous operations, and that it doesn't have enough information to even *potentially* deal with asynchronous operations.  It simply doesn't have the tools to do it, even if it tried to.  Since it can only accept synchronous operations, the only way it has to run them in parallel is to use multiple threads, and that's only the appropriate thing to do if the operations you're trying to parallelize are CPU bound operations.

Comment: @Servy Oh I see where you're coming from. I guess in this instance the semaphore doesn't block an entire thread when it causes a wait to occur, otherwise the result of both bits of code is largely the same.

Comment: @Servy - _if you do that you're creating tons and tons of threads just to have them all sit there doing nothing_ By your statement I agree 2nd approach is bad, but what about running them using first approach i.e. with `async`? It will not create multiple threads right?

Comment: @RahulSingh If you do it right, no, it will not need the work of multiple threads.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I thought if I queue the SP 150 at a time, won't that effect my DB? That's why I thought of splitting it in a batch of 20-30 and run. Which approach you suggest..?

Answer (score 11):

So you can use a Semaphore for this. The concept behind a semaphore is the night club bouncer scenario, where the bouncer has a limit to the amount of people (threads) allowed in the club (thread pool) and as people leave (threads finish) other people can enter (threads can continue), up to the limit.

All threads will be started, however it is the `WaitAsync()` which is blocking the thread from continuing. The `Release()` is signalling a thread re-entering the thread pool.

The delay here gives the effect of batching because each thread is roughly waiting the same amount of time, however, in reality it will be more likely that you'll see a few at a time.

Substitute `Delay(5000)` with random int to get a better look.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var runner = new SprocRunner(new DataAccess());

        var threads = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            threads.Add(runner.ExecuteSp($"Async {i}"));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(threads.ToArray());
    }
}

public class SprocRunner
{
    private readonly System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim batcher = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(10, 10);
    private readonly DataAccess da;

    public SprocRunner(DataAccess da)
    {
        this.da = da;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteSp(string asyncTaskName)
    {
        await batcher.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            await this.da.ExecuteSP(asyncTaskName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            batcher.Release();
        }
    }
}

public class DataAccess
{
    public Task ExecuteSP(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        return Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

### Why not to use Parallel

After reading papers from the likes of Stephen Toub, the case is, if you are doing lots of I/O bound tasks then in some cases using `Parallel` isn't a problem and it does allow you to get the job done. The things to consider is that thread creation isn't a non-negligible cost, and if you request more threads than are present in the ThreadPool it will have to inject new ones. This becomes a problem if you're in an environment which makes lots of use of threads like ASP.NET. Having tonnes of threads sitting around blocking on I/O work is really really bad and can bring your server to a stand still.

This is where using the `Task` abstraction really comes into its own, because you can run all these tasks and have then wait for the I/O response - but really importantly - they won't block any threads (other than the main thread waiting on the results), only once the I/O completes will treads be utilised briefly to process the results.

Comment: It would be better to use `SemaphoreSlim` and `WaitAsync`.

Comment: You also shouldn't have a static semaphore; it should be an instance field.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary will update. I last used this in a .NET 4 program

Comment: @CallumLinington - Thanks, I am testing this but it is taking lot of time. Sorry I don't have much knowledge on Parallel programming. Can you explain how is it different from `Parallel.For` with _MaxDegreeOfParallelism _ set as 5?

Comment: `Parallel.For` is for parallelism where as `Task` is being used for concurrency. `Parallel.For` is a construct for defining an action that should be run in parallel, where as `Task` is just a high level abstraction over the asynchronous concurrency pattern. Both are "safe" to use due to the fact they both use the Thread Pool to manage threads, however read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand the dangers of parallelism